sympy gradient of function of n-dim vector
I would simply like to define a symbolic function of this signature
: ℝ^ → ℝ
and obtain the gradient symbolically. The function does not have any concrete definition. What I am expecting is some symbolic expression like '∇()'.
When I try this in sympy, it gives me zero !

Can anyone explain me how to do this properly in sympy ?
PS: I am quite new to sympy.

EDIT: Following @smichr's suggestion, I tried changing the names to english alphabets. Still the same issue.


Check your version of SymPy. With __version__ -> 1.11.1 I get a symbolic derivative, not 0.

oh, mine is 1.12. let me downgrade and see

um, nope. it still gives 0. I updated the image with version shown. also tried 1.11.1 -- still same.

does sympy.vector have what you want?

@hpaulj I guess that's not what I want. I work in machine learning domain which uses abstract vector/matrices of arbitrary dimensions and do not need to expose its components. I found vector module to be too verbose for my use -- it often leads to expressions cluttered with the constituent components which is of no use to me. I came across this MatrixSymbol which is way better, but stuck at this issue.

I believe that you are looking for a functionality already requested on this sympy issue, but not yet implemented...

Thanks, those are very relevant discussions. I am surprised that sympy still doesn't have a full-featured abstract vector and matrix manipulation capabilities. This is my 2nd (unsuccessful) try of using sympy in my ML/Stat theory work. I will soon open a fresh discussion on the sympy repo.

a SymPy issue relating to this was opened: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/26950
